# Problems with scanf and strings in a while loop

Tags: c, string, pointers, scanf

I don't understand what's wrong with this part of code of my program.
I'm using a while cicle for asking the user to insert a string that will be saved to a temporary (char *name) string and then passed as argument of a function. However the problem is when I use scanf function. This is the code:

```
char *name;
size_t i=0;

while(i<size){
    printf("Insert #%zu item name: ",i+1);
    scanf("%s",name);
    printf("Insert #%zu item price: ",i+1);
    scanf("%u",&price);
    item=item_cons(item,name,price);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: `However the problem is when I use scanf function` what is it?

Comment: Oh sorry I forget to insert that. Ok this is the problem: When I insert the string it prints for (size) times insert 1-2-3-4-...-size item name and insert 1..size item price

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
scanf("%s",name);
```

you did not allocate memory for `name`, the pointer. It points to *invalid* memory location and attempt to use it to store any value will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to allocate memory to `name` before you can use that to store anything in the memory pointed by it. You can either

- make `name` an array, like `char name[32] = {0};` and then use it like `scanf("%31s",name);` (*usually preferred*)

or,

- allocate dynamic memory to `char *name`, using `malloc()` or family.

Comment: I used name=malloc(sizeof(char*)*size); and it works Thanks you!

Comment: @Gio No, it does not look like, rather, you may want `name= malloc( sizeof(*name) * size);` Note: 1) You need to check for success of `malloc()` 2) You got to free the memory afterwards. What's the problem with the array?

Comment: Wait, just because _it works_, doe not mean it's correct. `name=malloc(sizeof(char*)*size);` is wrong, as you want to allocate memory for `char`s, not `char *`s... see my previous comment ^.

Comment: Better to say `name` lacks initialization - its contents are not specified.  C does not specify the `name` points to an invalid memory location.

Comment: BTW: "attempt to use (by de-referencing) to store any value will invoke undefined behavior." is true and  somewhat surprisingly even reading the _pointer_ value is UB.

Answer (score 0):

try to use
char name[100]={'\0'}
this assumes that the larger name you will get is a 10

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue